# Comparing means (int) by zipcode (factor) in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, lm, anova

I have a list of zipcodes and the number of covid deaths per zipcode in a data frame (not real numbers, just examples):

| City | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Richmond | 552 |
| Las Vegas | 994 |
| San Francisco | 388 |

I want to see if there is any relationship between zipcode and the total number of deaths.

I made an LM model using the LM() function

```
mod_zip <- lm(Total ~ City, data=zipcode)
```

But when I call summary(mod_zip) I get NA for everything except the estimate column.

| Coefficients | Estimate | Std. Error | t value | Pr(> | t) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CityRichmond | 2851 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| CityLasVegas | -2604 | NA | NA | NA | NA |
| CitySanFran | -966 | NA | NA | NA | NA |

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unclear what you're looking for, but I don't think `lm` is the right approach. It sounds like you have a range of death numbers for different cities and you want to test if the variation is more than what you'd expect if deaths occurred independent of City. Perhaps more relevant approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_test

Comment: Do you actually only have one observation per city? That isn't going to make for much of a linear momdel

Comment: Yes it's only one observation/row per city. I am having problems with DF errors. The data is fairly standard so I thought something like ANOVA would be more appropriate but didn't think about the variance/DF. Great point. I'll try that in R next.

Answer (score 1):

`lm` will turn the factor into one-hot columns, so you have a parameter for each city except one and a global intercept.

Then (assuming, without seeing your data) you try to estimate n data points with n parameters which it manages to do but it doesn't have enough degrees of freedom to get a standard error.

Simplified Example to reproduce:

```
df <- data.frame(x = LETTERS, y = rnorm(26), stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
fit <- lm(y~x, data = df)
summary(fit)
```

You will see an Intercept and parameters B through Z (26 parameters for 26 observations), the degrees of freedom are thus 0 hence the standard errors and related metrics not calculable.

Comment: This is correct. I get an error when I tried to use ANOVA functions as well. What would be the best statistical approach for the data? I intend to add in population and calc percentage of population as well but I feel like I need to figure this out first.

Comment: Anova has the same issue as lm because it's actually doing the exact same thing. You will have use different imputs or do some feature engineering (aggregate zip codes at a higher level like state or turn them into latitude and longitude or republican vote share in the last election or something) in a way that addresses the *actual* question you are trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to test whether City is a relevant factor for predicting deaths. In other words, would you expect to see the observed range of values if each death had an equal chance of occurring in any City?

My intuition on this would be that there should certainly be a difference, based on many City-varying differences in demographics, rules, norms, vaccination rates, and the nature of an infectious disease that spreads more if more people are infected to begin with.

If you want to confirm this intuition, you could use simulation. Let's say all Cities had the same underlying risk rate of 800, and all variation was totally due to chance.

```
set.seed(2021)
Same_risk = 800
Same_risk_deaths = rpois(100, Same_risk)
mean(Same_risk_deaths)
sd(Same_risk_deaths)
```

Here, the observed mean is indeed close to 800, with a standard deviation of around 3% of the average value.

If we instead had a situation where some cities, for whatever combination of reasons, had different risk factors (say, 600 or 1000), then we could see the same average around 800, but with a much higher standard deviation around 25% of the average value.

```
Diff_risk = rep(c(600, 1000), 50)
Diff_risk_deaths = rpois(100, Diff_risk)
mean(Diff_risk_deaths)
sd(Diff_risk_deaths)
```

I imagine your data does not look like the first distribution and is instead much more varied.